# Did'n do nothing using if statement to go to another page PHP

Tags: php, header

I want go to another page if the condition allowed. But when i submit the button it just like refresh the page. it doesn't direct to another page.
I have already read another question remain same but did not change.

Here is my code :

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['login']))
{
$nik = $_POST['nik'];
$pswd = $_POST['pswd'];
if ((empty($nik)) or (empty($pswd)))
echo "Data masih ada yang kosong<br/><br/>";
else
{
    include("sss_connection.php");
    $connection = mysql_connect($server,$user,$pass);
    $db = mysql_select_db("skripsi");
    if(!$connection)
    {
        echo "Database belum terkoneksi<br/><br/>";}
        elseif(!$db)
    {
        echo "Database Tidak Ada<br/><br/>";}
        else
    {
        $sql1 = "select count(*) as cek,kd_jabatan from datakaryawan where nik='".$nik."' and password='".$pswd."'";
        //$exec = mysql_query($sql1);
        $ambil_data = mysql_query($sql1);
        if ($data = mysql_fetch_array($ambil_data))
        {
            $cek = $data["cek"];
            $jabatan = $data["kd_jabatan"];
        }
        if(($jabatan) == 0)
        {
            echo "Anda gagal Login, NIK / Password salah<br/><br/>";
        }
        else
        {
            header("Location: sss_header.php");
        }
    }   
}
}?>
```

And here is my html code :

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post">
<div style="float:left;margin-left:35%;margin-top:5%;">
<center><strong><font size="6">Login</font></strong></center>
</br></br>
<table style="float:left;margin-left:5%;">      
        <tr>
            <td width=84>NIK</td>
            <td width=10>:</td>
            <td width=30><input type="text" name="nik" size=30 onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" style="width: 217px" autofocus></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width=70>Password</td>
            <td width=10>:</td>
            <td width=30><input type="password" name="pswd" size=30 style="width: 217px"></td>
        </tr>
        </table><blockquote><blockquote><br/><br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Login"  name="login" style="float:left; margin-left:45px; margin-top:12px;">
        <input type="submit" value="Daftar" name="daftar" style="float:left; margin-left:26px; margin-top:12px;">
        <input type="reset" value="Clear" style="float:left; margin-left:26px; margin-top:12px;">
    </form>
    </div>
    <div style="float:left;margin-left:35%;margin-top:5%;">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please create a minimal, verifiable example of your code. [Check here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to find out how. We have no idea if those if-statements have the desired result or not.

Comment: Are these two code segments in the same file?

Comment: You can't do like this. Why ? Because, when you execute your PHP. you already change page (in your case you refresh page). The best way is to use ajax. And redirect with javascript.

Comment: if you are posting to another page then you need to add "method" attribute to form tag and if you are posting on same page then first of all you need to check if any types of output started before "header("Location: sss_header.php");" because header will not work if output started so try by changing error_reporting to display all errors and wornings.

Comment: thx Flechenoir. I was just remembered that PHP is refreshing page. Please move your comment to answer so i can give point.

Answer (score 1):

you have to specified the action attribute on your form tag, should be like this:

```
   <form method="post" action="anotherplace.php">
```